# how to only scroll the children inside scrollview that has another scrollview

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have ListView and the children that has pdf document wrap inside singleChildScrollView want to only scroll the singleChildScrollView and not the listView
after expansion

Below is my code

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15, top: 10),
      width: size.width,
      child: Text("Title should be Pinned",
        textAlign: TextAlign.end,
      ),
    ),
    SizedBox(
      height: 20,
    ),
    Theme(
      data: ThemeData(
        accentColor: Colors.black,
        primaryColor: Colors.white24,
      ),
      child: Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: data.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, i) => ExpansionTile(
            title: Center(
              child: Text(
                "After Expansion this should be pinned and only children should be scrollable"
              ),
            ),
            children: [
              Container(
                child: SingleChildScrollView( //should be scrollable on expanded and not the title of ExpansionTile
                  child: SfPdfViewer.network(
                    '$url',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 1):

warp your widget in a container and give it a height
use the following parameters inside the scroll widget

shrinkwrap: false,
primary: true

Comment: is there any other widget that will make things easier i have implemented the CustomScrollView, SliverPersistentHeader, SliverFixedExtentList as a solution but cannot make it expandable

Comment: if you want to make it expandable and uses its height dynamically
then just use shrinkwrap: true

Answer (score 0):

```
physics:  NeverScrollableScrollPhysics():
```

Add This Line to Your Widget then it will work

Comment: added to listview and i'm not able to scroll but i want the Container(
                child: SingleChildScrollView able to scroll how can i achieve it?

Comment: now add physics:  Scrollable(); to the SingleChildScrollView then it will work

Comment: getting error The argument type 'Scrollable' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ScrollPhysics

Comment: SingleChildScrollView(
            physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),

Comment: ListView.builder(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
                children: [
                   SingleChildScrollView(
                        physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()

not working

Comment: ListView.builder( sinkwrap: true, physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() children: [ SingleChildScrollView( physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()  Now Check using Sinkwrap

Comment: remove the expanded widget

Comment: RenderFlex overflowed by 27272 pixels on the bottom

Comment: ListView.builder( sinkWrap : true, physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() ,
           itemCount: data.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, i) => ExpansionTile(
            title: Center(
              child: Text(
                "After Expansion this should be pinned and only children should be scrollable"
              ),
            ),
            children: [
              Container(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(,physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()
                         ## Remove the Expanded Widget and do like this it will work

Comment: nope not working added to body of scaffold and removed everything still not able to scroll
only that there is no property sinkWrap used shrinkWrap